# Force Visual Studio Code to highlight part of the code in different language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing SQL code in a .php file. Can I set a hint/comment for Visual Studio Code to highlight that part of the code in SQL syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't do it. Here's an opened issue [Universal Language Injections #1751](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1751).